# using an array as a source in autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I can't seem to get this to work, I have also tried using a string and string list but I didn't have any luck with that either.

```
@{
    List<string> yyy = new List<string>();
    foreach (var x in Model)
    {
        yyy.Add(x.Name);
    }
    string[] myArray = yyy.ToArray();
}

<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = @myArray;
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

The error I get:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 70, column 39 in http://localhost:42697/Units

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

In the code it shows:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = System.String[];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try encoding your array to json:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(myArray));
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

which should then look like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ["name1", "name2", "name3", etc];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH.

I have seriously spent the past like 2 hours trying to get this tiny thing to work in 100 different ways and nothing was taking. You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = =[<%foreach (var s in myArray){%>'<%=s%>',<%}%>];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```